# cannot convert value of type 'ResultElement' to type '_?' in coercion

Tags: ios, swift

a given example in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/lazysequenceprotocol

```
struct LazyScanIterator<Base: IteratorProtocol, ResultElement>: IteratorProtocol {
    mutating func next() -> ResultElement? {
        return nextElement.map{ (result) in
            nextElement = base.next().map{ nextPartialResult(result, $0) }
            return result
        }
    }

    private var nextElement: ResultElement?
    private var base: Base
    private let nextPartialResult: (ResultElement, Base.Element) -> ResultElement
}

struct LazyScanSequence<Base: Sequence, ResultElement>: LazySequenceProtocol // Chained operations on self are lazy, too
{
    private let initial: ResultElement
    private let base: Base
    private let nextPartialResult: (ResultElement, Base.Element) -> ResultElement

    func makeIterator() -> LazyScanIterator<Base.Iterator, ResultElement> {
        return LazyScanIterator(nextElement: initial, base: base.makeIterator(), nextPartialResult: nextPartialResult)
    }
}
```

Copied and ran same code, I got the errors:

> cannot convert value of type 'ResultElement' to expected argument type '_?'
>
> return LazyScanIterator(nextElement: ***initial***, base: base.makeIterator(), nextPartialResult: nextPartialResult)

Can anyone explain to me how can I fix this?